# UI tests failing in Xcode 11, but used to pass in Xcode 10

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing, xcode11

I recently upgraded to Xcode 11, and my UI tests that used to pass in Xcode 10, are now failing, no code changes were made, and now its failing to find an element on the screen that it used to find

I tried setting the isAccessibilityElement to true for the element I want, like I used to, and I can see it on the Accessibility inspector, but when I run my UI tests and try "po XCUIApplication()" the element I am looking for is not found, any thoughts on what could be wrong? I have been busting my head trying to solve this, but I don't know what's wrong anymore

Answer (score 0):

Never mind turns out I had a button for a view, and Xcode 11 is more strict when it comes to UI testing than Xcode 10 used to be, so after changing the button to a view instead, the tests were passing again